# Approximately how many 3.5-inch floppy disks have been produced before manufacturing was stopped?

Tags: floppy-disk

3.5-inch floppy disks are not produced anymore, with *I think* Sony being the last to stop manufacturing in March 2011. Meaning that all floppy disks that exist are currently in circulation and the supply won't grow but only decrease over time as floppies degrade and fail.

I am not sure who the leading manufacturers were but did they publish data about this? Or is there any estimate available of amount of 3.5-inch floppies that were produced in the world?

This is probably an impossible question to answer but I couldn't find an answer and I'd like to find an educated estimate at least.

Comment: Looking in my old computer stuff cabinet, I think 3.5-inch floppies reproduce on their own - sure seem to be more than I remember in there...

Comment: According to this article, https://www.pcworld.com/article/512363/article-4108.html Sony was one of a handful companies still selling floppies in 2010 (when they decided to stop selling March 2011) So, nothing says that Sony actually produced floppy disks 201, nor does it say what the other 3 or 4 companies decided to do. What are the proofs that no one is still producing floppy disks?

Comment: The article https://www.pcworld.com/article/512363/article-4108.html also gives a small hint about the volume. 2010 the domestic Japanese market was about 12 million disks. We will probably talk about 10⁹ or even 10¹0 disks per year during the years when 3.5 floppies were the thing.

Comment: Judging by the ratings of floppies currently being sold online, it seems that "degrade and fail" applies to unused stock sitting on shelves even.

Comment: @MichaelTracy Does it? If so, how fast and under what conditions? That sounds like an entirely legit new question on this topic to me. If you won't post it, I might later.

Comment: @Bob Ortiz - I think that probably falls into the "unanswerable" column. I was looking for some floppies for work (we still use a *few*), but I couldn't find a vendor with good enough ratings for the offerings (to be fair, I only looked at a few) and I would note that subjective ratings on floppies don't rule out possible issues with older drives.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because 3.5" floppies are still being produced, so (a) the answer will change daily and (b) since they are still being produced, 3.5" floppies are arguably not Retrocomputing.

Comment: There's one company who would know. AOL.  3/4 of all floppy production went to them.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I wrote a comment which addresses your part a) in Raffzahn's answer. For b), I don't know if there's a formal definition of retro used by this site but floppy disks are pretty retro to me! I'd love to see how someone goes about estimating this

Comment: This seems like one of those ridiculous interview questions that US tech companies used to be famous for!

Comment: @another-dave Maybe. It for sure is based on typical PR buzz. Here Sony 'calling off' the age of floppies to present themself as leading into a bright future. Ready made to be picked up by media outlets to create another 'important' news bit they need to fill their pages, which in turn means it gets reprinted a lot and found all over the net in one way or another.

Comment: yes they're still being produced in some dinky quantity compared to the heyday, but so?  there should be some order-of-magnitude answer possible.  some industry reports available from back in the day, gartner stuff, etc.  this question shouldn't be _closed_ because I think an answer is possible even if us retro-geeks aren't able to supply it - some econ/business/research librarian type could.

Answer (score 23):

To my understanding [Taiwanese CMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMC_Magnetics) still produces 3.5 inch diskettes in PRC.

By now they seem to be the last major supplier. They became the biggest supplier of diskettes already in the 1990s, doing production for most brands from Maxwell to Verbatim, later they also acquired many (former) famous brand names (including Verbatim). They did (and still do) the same for optical media.

Their strategy seems to be to continue supporting floppy and CD/etc. as long as there are buyers. After all, why give up a business if there's still money to earn with no new investment needed.

Companies like AWP still sell 3.5er by the box (250 box that is :))

> Meaning that all floppy disks [...] only decrease over time as floppies degrade and fail.

Well, sure, everything is will fade eventually - and most things *way* before the sun goes red giant. At the same time it's not as fast as people might believe. FD have, well stored, a shelf life of many decades. I routinely use floppies 30+ years old without much hassles. In fact, I remember way more bad diskettes around 1980 than today,but that might be more due the cheap ass me buying only the lowest priced ones. Everything past mid 1980s, and especially 3.5 after mid 1990s is quite reliable even 30-50 years later. Of course, this is just anecdotal, YMMV.

Damage is mostly to storage. I've taken 5.25 collections stored in dry attics in mild climate for 40 years and each and every diskette worked, while others stored in some garage in Florida were already falling apart after barely more than 20 years. and falling apart is to be taken literally here. Not just rust at metal parts, but magnetic surface sliding away from carrier film.

**Diskettes are stored at moderate temperature and shrink wrapped (or at average humidity), will serve us for decades to come. No need to worry.**

Comment: on the other hand moisture kills them for sure

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Note the 'average humidity part ... so neither Nevada nor Guiana :)

Comment: I wish I knew that when I decided to store my amiga originals in a garage that was slightly flooded, in the south of France (not exacly Guiana)... the moisture killed 30% of the disks, even if they were in a posso box, in a drawer...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Sorry to hear that ... then again, being just Amiga diskettes. not much is lost <DuckAndRun/> More serious, it's really interesting to learn how durable diskettes can be when stored proper and how easy they fall apart if not.

Comment: +1 then later realized "not an answer to the actual question" then "can't truly answer because still being produced according to your answer", therefore VTC.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Somehow I never can make it right. this time I avoided to argue that there is (to **my** knowledge) no answer, and again it some how doesn't fit expectation :(

Comment: And their disks were junk compared to the 80s floppies. Why? Dunno.

Comment: It's relevant to the question to know that some disks are still being made. However, I imagine that the quantity produced per year currently is a very small proportion of the total quantity produced until now. So it would still make sense to estimate the total that have been produced until this point, I doubt that any such estimates would be accurate to within the amount currently produced by Taiwanese CMC in a year

Comment: By that metric, Ford Model-T's are still being produced, in that if you're a Hollywood studio making a movie set in the 1910's, you can spend a bunch of money to get custom antique replicas built.  Though I guess that wouldn't be *quite* the same thing, as you're not getting one from *Ford*, the original manufacturer...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I agree, as soon as you point out some Hollywood factory producing several hundred Model T per year on original production lines. Can you?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact "Your assumptions are wrong" is a valid answer.

Comment: Note that 3.5" disks **wern't all** 1.44MB - 720K were available.

Comment: @Raffzahn with the logic "floppies are still being produced" > not retro > close. You can close 1.220 questions. https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/search?q=floppy

Comment: @BobOrtiz Mind to explain wh you're addressing _me_ with that?

Comment: @Raffzahn honestly assumption based on your previous questioning on "ontopicness" of similar questions. If mistaken I am sorry and you can happily ignore it but I thought this would be most likely.

Comment: @BobOrtiz Well, you're right, I'm critical of questions asking off topic an especially non answerable question. This one does not fall into the off-topic area, but is clearly non answerable by definition, as it's next to impossible to prove something doesn't happen. Being not fully thought true isn't a reason to close on itself. I simply feel we should strive to a minimum quality. Still, it seems inappropriate to assume without any proof - or do you see any comment of me calling for closure? Even more so as I provided an answer?

Comment: @Raffzahn As said, it's pure assumption. If not applicable I apologize.